# Jquery select li text after five second

Tags: jquery, html-lists

can any one please help me on this?
i want to console.log every text from li 5 second after after.
but this code console all li text after first five second

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="phrase">
       <ul class="items">
           <li id="load">TEXT1</li>
           <li id="load">TEXT2</li>
           <li id="load">TEXT3</li>
      </ul>
   </div>

   <script>
      var phrases = [];

      setTimeout(function(){
         $('.phrase').each(function(){
             var phrase;
             $(this).find('li').each(function(){
                 // cache jquery object
                 var current = $(this);
                 phrase = current.text();
                 console.log(phrase);
             });
         });
       }, 5000);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: id should be unqiue load

Comment: remove the find and change your first selector to `$('.phrase li')`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to repeatedly log the contents of the <li> elements to the console, not just once?

Comment: The problem is, that you use your each function inside the Timeout function which results in that you get all the text every five seconds. To change this, first open your foreach function and then set the timeout function to get the li text.
Greetz

Comment: Use setInterval (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var next = $(".phrase").find('li:eq(0)');
var inter = setInterval(function () {
   console.log( next.text());
    next = next.next();
    if(!next.length){
        clearInterval(inter);
    }

}, 5000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/24427kda/10/)**

Answer (score 3):

I create this using Recursion:

```js
(function myLoop(i, ctn) {
  /// <summary>
  /// find length of li elements and create a recursion
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="i">length of li elements</param>
  /// <param name="ctn">a counter</param>
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("body").append($(".items li").eq(ctn).text());
    ctn++;
    if (--i) myLoop(i, ctn); //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
  }, 1000)

})($(".items li").length, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phrase">
  <ul class="items">
    <li class="load">TEXT1</li>
    <li class="load">TEXT2</li>
    <li class="load">TEXT3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all like Bala suggested, make sure you have unique ID for your elements.

Your JS code can be changed to:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var phrases = [];
    var timeOut = 5000;  

    $('.phrase li').each(function(){
       var current = $(this);
       var phrase = current.text();

       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(phrase);
       }, timeOut);

      timeOut += 5000;
    });
});
```

You have to set the timeout everytime you get a new li

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6b87mg6/

Comment: i think this will set all three timeouts at the same time so all three will be printed at the same time

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$('.phrase').each(function(){
    var settimeout = 5000;
    $(this).find('li').each(function(){
        var phrase;
        var current = $(this);
        phrase = current.text();
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(phrase);
            alert(phrase);
        },settimeout );
        settimeout = settimeout + 5000;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var phrases = [];

setTimeout(function(){
    $('.phrase li').each(function(){
        var phrase;
        var current = $(this);
        phrase = current.text();
        console.log(phrase);
    });
}, 5000);
```

working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/tiyamo/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
    var text = [];
    $("li.load").each(function(){
       text.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(text.join(", "));
}, 1000);
```